# Warning about FontAwesomeIcon when using in Typescript file

Tags: typescript, next.js, font-awesome

I'm using NextJS with Typescript and when i'm import FontAweSomeIcon to use like this
`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck as any} />`
it got this warning from console "Warning: FontAwesomeIcon: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead."

Can you guys help me to how to remove or fix that warning

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. But, after updating each Font Awesome dependency, the error message was gone.

Execute the following in your terminal inside your project directory:

```
npm i @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@latest @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@latest @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons@latest
```

Warning: this will install the latest version to each of these packages, so be cafeful because may break things.